# update panel in master page and asyncpostbacktrigger in content page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages

I have a cart in master page that this cart is inside update panel.
In my content page I have a listview that in this listview exist linkbutton for add product to my cart.
I want to add product to cart using these linkbuttons without refresh, and cart is updated.
I have this code in my content page:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePanel up = (this.Master.Master.FindControl("UpCart")) as UpdatePanel;
        AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
        trigger.ControlID = lvNewProducts.UniqueID;
        trigger.EventName = "ItemCommand";
        up.Triggers.Add(trigger);

    }
```

But my page is refreshed when I click in link button.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want a partial post back and you are getting a full post back?

I think you can't add AsyncPostbackTriggers to an update panel from a different naming container. You did try with lvNewProducts.UniqueID to set ControlID, which is normally set with the ID. So that's a hint that this might be the case.

What you can do is calling RegisterAsyncPostBackControl on the ScriptManager.
Assuming your ScriptManager is in your master page and it's ID is myScriptManager you have todo the following:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager myScriptManager = (this.Master.Master.FindControl("myScriptManager")) as ScriptManager;
    if (scriptManager != null) {
        scriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lvNewProducts);
    }
}
```

That replaced your code and should result in a partial post back. The link to your update panel to get updated is still missing, so you should do the following to get it updated in the ItemCommand event handler (e.g. if you set OnItemCommand="ListViewClicked":

```
protected void ListViewClicked(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    //Do whatever necessary

    //Now update your update panel
    UpdatePanel up = (this.Master.Master.FindControl("UpCart")) as UpdatePanel;
    if (up != null) {
        up.Update();
    }
}
```